# Failed to resolve component: swiper-container in vue js 3 project

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a project that use framework7 with Vue JS 3. I'm using Swiper.js for slide effects with tabs, it works fine but I keep getting this swiper-container warning. I tried re-adding the swiper.js even tried run serve couple of times. But keep getting this warning.

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: swiper-container If this is a
> native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component
> resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.    at
>     at     at <F7App el="#app" name="Mobile"
> theme="auto"  ... >    at

```
<div class="content-bottom">
    <div class="tab-container">
        <div class="display-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <a href="#tab1" class="tab-link tab-link-active">
                <span class="tab-box">&nbsp;</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#tab2" class="tab-link">
                <span class="tab-box">&nbsp;</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#tab3" class="tab-link">
                <span class="tab-box">&nbsp;</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#tab4" class="tab-link">
                <span class="tab-box">&nbsp;</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <swiper-container class="tabs">
        <swiper-slide id="tab1" class="page-content tab tab-active">
            <div class="app-form-wrapper">
                
            </div>
        </swiper-slide>
        <!-- Tab 2 -->
        <swiper-slide id="tab2" class="page-content tab">
            <div class="app-form-wrapper">
                
            </div>
        </swiper-slide>
        <!-- Tab 3 -->
        <swiper-slide id="tab3" class="page-content tab">

        </swiper-slide>
        <swiper-slide id="tab4" class="page-content tab">

        </swiper-slide>
    </swiper-container>
</div>
```

I have also registered the component like this.

```
<script>

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';

import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
register();

export default {
    components: {
        Swiper, 
        SwiperSlide
    },
```

Dependencies...

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-legacy": "^2.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "dom7": "^4.0.4",
    "framework7": "^7.0.8",
    "framework7-icons": "^5.0.5",
    "framework7-vue": "^7.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "linq": "^4.0.0",
    "material-icons": "^1.12.0",
    "mitt": "^3.0.0",
    "skeleton-elements": "^4.0.0",
    "swiper": "^11.0.5",
    "vue": "^3.2.40",
    "vue-chartjs": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-chartkick": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-numeric": "^2.5.0",
    "vue3-draggable": "^2.0.9",
    "vue3-touch-events": "^4.1.0",
    "vuedraggable": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.1.2",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.40",
    "cpy-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.8.2",
    "terser": "^5.15.1",
    "uglify-js": "^3.17.4",
    "uglifyjs-folder": "^3.3.0",
    "vite": "^3.1.4",
    "workbox-cli": "^6.5.4"
  }
```

Comment: "_But keep getting this warning_" ...what warning? Please add this information to your question.

Answer (score -1):

In swiper v11 there is no `<swiper-container></swiper-container>`, there is - `<swiper></swiper>`.
https://swiperjs.com/vue

Comment: Swiper Vue components will likely to be removed in future versions. It is recommended to migrate to Swiper Element instead.